# Get the ends of xml children attributes *url's in php?

Tags: php, xml, explode

Ok i have an xml file like this. . .

```
<parent> 
 <x url="example/656577/07234/random.swf"/>
 <x url="example1/609456/67856/random1.swf"/>
 <x url="example2/376987/09365/random2.swf"/>
 <x url="example3/956743/04762/random3.swf"/>
 <x url="example4/678543/95265/random4.swf"/>
</parent>
```

what happens in the xml file all the x children url's change all the time but always in 3 directorys, what i want to do is to get just the ends of each children's url like. . .

> random.swf  random1.swf  random2.swf  random3.swf  random4.swf

I am not familiar with explode but is that a option any answer welcome.

Comment: You need to try. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php and at http://php.net/path_info to get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok yes i took a look at the link you provided, I found it useful thanks for pointing me in the right direction i am now currently using

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('example4/678543/95265/random4.swf');
echo $path_parts['filename'].".".$path_parts['extension'];
```

for the problem i had thanks again.